# so when will ubuntu touch come out on samsung galaxy?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

just wondering because i've ubuntu on my desktop works effortlessly and wanna make the switch but also wondering if play store is compatible with operating system or perhaps built in?

Comment: samsung galaxy express model number GT-I8730

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be meeting the requirements for the Ubuntu touch installation, I know that there are some phones from Meizu that already come with Ubuntu touch as the OS to power their phones because they are partners of Canonical.

At the moment it can only be installed on Google Nexus devices for testing purpose only.

It will have a different store and it will NOT be compatible with Android apps, it will have its own market.